# var modification issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below, I have a piece of javascript code.

```
var htmlBlurb = '<div> hello <font color=red>world</font>!!!</div>';
$(htmlBlurb).find('font').each(function(e){
    $(this).html("Javascript");
});
console.log(htmlBlurb);
```

I am expecting the output in htmlBlurb as

```
<div> hello <font color=red>Javascript</font>!!!</div>
```

But `htmlBlurb` is not changed.

Can someone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: you never stored the result of `$(htmlBlurb)` to `htmlBlurb`, therefore it's just a string

Comment: Please don't use the `<font>` element; it was deprecated a looong time ago.

Comment: But they go great with `<marquee>`

Comment: htmlBlurb is not a proper selector, it is just a string. You need to add a class like .hello to your html and use that in the jQuery selector. Right now your not selecting anything to manipulate.

Comment: @bradcush it wasn't intended to be a selector, it's an html string which is perfectly valid for passing to `jQuery()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htmlBlurb` is a string. While `$(htmlBlurb)` creates an element and stores it temporarily, it does not modify the original string, just like running operations on `$('a')` does not  modify the string literal `'a'`.

Instead, do the following:

```
var htmlBlurb = '<div> hello <font color=red>world</font>!!!</div>';
var blurb=$(htmlBlurb)
blurb.find('font').each(function(e){
    $(this).html("Javascript");
});
console.log(blurb.wrapAll('<div></div>').parent().html());
```

Comment: I am seeing only Javascript in the console. I am trying to get htmlBlurb with World replaced by javascript

Comment: @javaMan Fixed, using solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15663100/1198729)

Comment: I just see this <font color="red">Javascript</font>

Comment: @javaMan Try again, I made a mistake while updating it. Fixed.